# Ubuntu 18.04 Bluetooth Inactive (dead)

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, bluetooth

I have an ubuntu 18.04 that has a "ASUS PCE-AC55BT B1 AC1200 Wireless Bluetooth 4.2 PCIe/Mpcie Adapter." The wifi and bluetooth were working fine for a couple months, but recently the bluetooth has broken (the wifi still works).

I am pretty sure I have tried every result on the first 3 pages of Google when searching this problem, but I cannot figure out why the bluetooth is not working. I have spent over 8 hours trying to fix this very annoying problem, so I would be very thankful if anyone can help.

Here is some more information and things I have tried.

I have a dual boot pc (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04). The bluetooth does not work on either and the wifi works on both. This makes me think there is something wrong on a very low level (hardware or bios drivers).

I have even tried buying a replacement for my old wifi/bluetooth adapter of the same model because I thought maybe the bluetooth had broke for some reason. The new one also has the same problem. I have tried moved the card into a different pci slot with no luck. This means the hardware is not broken.

The problem seems to lie in the fact that no bluetooth adapter is detected. When I do rfkill list, I only see Wireless LAN, but no bluetooth.

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

When I run systemctl status bluetooth, I get

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
 Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

I have also confirmed I have the newest versions of bluez, bluetooth, and bluez-tools.

When I try to run Bluetooth Manager, I get an error

```
Bluez daemon is not running, blueman-manager cannot continue. This probably means that there were no Bluetooth adapters detected or Bluetooth daemon was not started.
```

I tried starting the bluetooth daemon with both of these lines, but systemctl status bluetooth still shows bluetooth as inactive (dead) after these commands.

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
[ ok ] Starting bluetooth (via systemctl): bluetooth.service.
```

I am honestly not even sure what to try anymore since nothing seems to be working. The weirdest part to me is that the bluetooth was working fine for a couple months and then it stopped working. The only thing I can remember changing is setting acpi=force in /etc/default/grub, but I removed this later after I found the bluetooth wasn't working. I am not sure if this is correlated since I didn't test the bluetooth right before/after.

Comment: Check if there is some option on your BIOS that disables Bluetooth. Also, check if there is some physical button or combination of keys that switch the Bluetooth function of your computer.

Comment: I have tried to turn bluetooth on the bios but when I go on the uefi bios Advanced > Devices > Onboard Devices, I do not see anywhere that says Bluetooth. I looked it up and it should be there, but I am not sure why it isn't. Is it possible that the bios need to detect the bluetooth adapter for the option to appear in the bios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was my motherboard's usb 2.0 ports were not working. This led the bluetooth to not work because the bluetooth was connected to the motherboard through the usb 2.0 port.